# RxJava retryWhen with updated value + concurrency

Tags: android, concurrency, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I'd like to verify two things:

1. if the way I use `retryWhen` is correct or not. Basically, when an exception is caught, I want to get an updated value and rerun the sequence.
2. if another function also needs `value`, how to make it waits for `updateValue` to complete in the first instance? I've played with `.share()` and `RxReplayingShare` but I'm not sure how to use those properly.

```
val value = 0

@Test
fun test() {
    executeFunction()
        .retryWhen { errors -> errors.flatMap { error ->
                if (error is WrongValue) {
                    updateValue()
                       .doOnSuccess { value = it }
                       .toObservable()
                } else {
                    Observable.error(error)
                }
            }
        }
}

fun executeFunction(): Single<Int> =
    if (value == 0) {
        Single.error(WrongValue())
    } else {
        Single.just(value)
    }

fun updateValue(): Single<Int> = Single.just(1)
```